# The Palindromic Odometer Puzzler: A Programmatic Solution

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, palindrome

That is a programmatic solution to a puzzler from **Car Talk**, its summary is:

> "I noticed that the last 4 digits were palindromic. I drove a mile,
>   and the last 5 were palindromic. I drove another mile and the middle 4
>   were palindromic, and the ends were not involved. And then one mile
>   later, all 6 digits were palindromic."

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    """Finds if a string is a plaindrome or not.

       string: str

       returns: bool
       """
    return string == string[::-1]

def find_puzzle_number():
    """Finds the number which was first seen.

       prints: int
       """
    guess = 100000  
    # the odometer shows only 6 numbers,
    # therefore 999999 is the last number to test.
    while guess < 1000000:
        if is_palindrome(str(guess)[2:]):  # last 4 numbers.       
            if is_palindrome(str(guess + 1)[1:]):  # last 5 numbers.
                if is_palindrome(str(guess + 2)[1:5]):  # middle 4 numbers.     
                    if is_palindrome(str(guess + 3)):
                        print(guess)

        guess = guess + 1

print('These are the possible odometer readings: ')
find_puzzle_number()
```

Notes:

- I'm a hobbyist and a beginner.
- I don't only want to optimize the code, but also my skills and style. Therefore any notes, advice and suggestions aren't only welcomed, but also encouraged!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation

```
   string: str

   returns: bool
```

is pretty obvious. I would skip it. The rest of the documentation can be more idiomatically written as

```
"""Return whether input sequence is a palindrome."""
```

(note `palindrome`, not `plaindrome`). I removed the term `string` because many sequence types can be palindromic, like `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`.

`find_puzzle_number` should `yield`, not `print`, its values.

I would change the documentation to specify the rules the output satisfy.

```
def find_puzzle_number():
    """Generates 6-digit integers, x, where all of

    * the last 4 digits of x,
    * the last 5 digits of x+1,
    * the middle 4 digits of x+2, and
    * all 6 digits of x+3

    are palindromes.
    """
    guess = 100000
    # the odometer shows only 6 numbers,
    # therefore 999999 is the last number to test.
    while guess < 1000000:
        if is_palindrome(str(guess)[2:]):  # last 4 numbers.
            if is_palindrome(str(guess + 1)[1:]):  # last 5 numbers.
                if is_palindrome(str(guess + 2)[1:5]):  # middle 4 numbers.
                    if is_palindrome(str(guess + 3)):
                        yield guess

        guess = guess + 1
```

The `while` should become a `for`

```
# 6 digit numbers
for guess in range(10**5, 10**6):
```

Then the `if` chain of `is_palindrome`s can be simplified:

```
valid = (
    is_palindrome(str(guess + 0)[2:]) and
    is_palindrome(str(guess + 1)[1:]) and
    is_palindrome(str(guess + 2)[1:5]) and
    is_palindrome(str(guess + 3))
)

if valid:
    yield guess
```

Now note something bad: `guess + 3`, can overflow. Either you want to clamp the code so that `guess + 3 < 10**6`, or you want to perform modular arithmetic.

Further, you don't know that `10**5` is a valid lower bound: `000000` is a valid reading. You can use `format(guess, "06")` to pad like this.

If you care about speed, PyPy makes the code run in about a tenth the time.

```
def is_palindrome(seq):
    """Return whether input sequence is a palindrome."""
    return seq == seq[::-1]

def find_puzzle_number():
    """Generates 6-digit integers, x, where all of

    * the last 4 digits of x,
    * the last 5 digits of x+1,
    * the middle 4 digits of x+2, and
    * all 6 digits of x+3

    are palindromes.
    """
    def as_reading(x):
        return format(x % 10**6, "06")

    # 6 digit numbers
    for guess in range(10**6):
        valid = (
            is_palindrome(as_reading(guess + 0)[2:]) and
            is_palindrome(as_reading(guess + 1)[1:]) and
            is_palindrome(as_reading(guess + 2)[1:5]) and
            is_palindrome(as_reading(guess + 3))
        )

        if valid:
            yield guess

print('These are the possible odometer readings: ')
for solution in find_puzzle_number():
    print(solution)
```

Note that there are simple optimizations you can apply. For instance, you can easily iterate over only those values for which `guess + 3` is a palindrome *by construction* - this reduces the values to iterate over from \$10^6\$ to \$10^3\$.

```
for guess_digits in range(10**3):
    # guess + 3 is a palindrome
    # NOTE: relies on correct handling of wrapping
    guess = guess_digits + int(format(guess_digits, "06")[::-1]) - 3
```

This makes the code basically instantaneous, so if optimizations were pointless to apply before they're most certainly pointless to apply now.

Comment: Thank you for this great review! I'd to ask about something. Why I should use "for" instead of "while"? What is the meaning of: "guess + 6 can overflow" (I'm a beginner)? It is said, in the full description of the puzzler, that the odometer shows only whole miles and he was driving. Therefore, is 10 ** 5 a valid lower bound? The puzzler is on:  http://www.cartalk.com/content/palindromic-odometer

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib Whoops, I meant "guess + *3* can overflow". IOW, if you guess `999 998`, then `is_palindrome(str(guess + 3))` will be operating on `is_palindrome(str(1000001))`! But that's not a valid reading! \$10^5\$ is a reasonable lower bound, but you could consider `0-1-2-3-2-0` to be a valid odometer reading.

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib You should use `for` instead of `while` because that's what `for` is designed to do. It looks nicer, and it reduces the chance of errors. There are only upsides!

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions, but I can't understand:                       for guess_digits in range(10**3):
    # guess + 3 is a palindrome
    # NOTE: relies on correct handling of wrapping
    guess = guess_digits + int(format(guess_digits, "06")[::-1]) - 3

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib `guess_digits` will be the bottom 3 digits of `guess + 3`. We can make `guess + 3` by flipping the bottom digits, as we know `guess + 3` is a palindrome. Thus, `guess + 3 == guess_digits + int(format(guess_digits, "06")[::-1])`. Then we need to get `guess`, so we subtract the `3` again. Note that this can become negative if `guess_digits == 0`, so you need to handle that. In my code, `as_reading` handles it by wrapping negative numbers back around to high numbers.

Comment: I struggle with it, but I can get an overview, and I will work on it. Can "guess_digits == 0" be handled by "range(1, 10 ** 3)"?

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib Yep, that's a valid way of doing it.